# What are the functions under textFieldMetadata do?

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm currently performing script optimization for a web project and I stumbled upon what seems to be a family of functions that run a bit slow (around 750ms). It shows on the Web Debugger as this:

```
Script Evaluated
    textFieldMetadata
       _cachedMetadataForFormWithTextField
       _collectControlMetadata
```

I'd assume that `textFieldMetadata` is the class, and the two below it are functions. But what do these functions do? I haven't seen it in my project, so it's probably something specific to Safari, and has to do with caching text field data.